# ¿Como puedo saber si un campo tipo JSON es igual a 'null' en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

Tengo una tabla donde la columna `data` es del tipo `JSON` y existen algunos registros cuyo valor en dicha columna es `'null'`.

Esta es la tabla:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `operations_invoice_details` (
  `idOperation` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idOrder` int UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Y estos son datos de ejemplo:

```sql
INSERT INTO `operations_invoice_details` 
(`idOperation`, `idOrder`, `data`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'null'), 
(2, 2, '{"a": 1}');
```

De este ejemplo, quisiera poder obtener el registro `(1, 1, 'null')` y para ello he realizado las siguientes consultas:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM operations_invoice_details
WHERE data = 'null';

# 0 resultados

SELECT *
FROM operations_invoice_details
WHERE data IS NULL;

# 0 resultados
```

Ninguna funciona... [acá la demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/78WqhshaDtg4oeyZJzu8Ju/0)

¿Como puedo hacer para obtener los registros donde `data` es `'null'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Pude llegar a una solución utilizando la función [`JSON_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-value) así:</s>

```sql
SELECT *
FROM operations_invoice_details
WHERE JSON_VALUE(data, '$') IS NULL;
```

[<kbd><s>Demo</s></kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/78WqhshaDtg4oeyZJzu8Ju/1)

Esta solución no sirve cuando el JSON es largo, [acá la demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/78WqhshaDtg4oeyZJzu8Ju/3)

---

## Actualización:

La solución que encontre fue utilizando la función [`JSON_TYPE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-type) así:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM operations_invoice_details
WHERE JSON_TYPE(data) = 'NULL';
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/78WqhshaDtg4oeyZJzu8Ju/5)

Comment: Otra que funciona es `json_keys(data) is null`.